# How to fold some lines which didn't separate by brace in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Before starting, I apologize for my poor English. probably it is hard to understanding what I mean. :)

In Visual Studio, some lines can be folded. Such as Tide by brace{}.

I mean this.

[image]

But I want to fold the lines didn't tide by anything.
this

[image]

Is there any way to fold that lines?

Comment: Which version of Visual Sudio are you using? In latest VS, you can fold any code.

Comment: VS 2017. any other way to fold code?not using #pragma region?

Comment: oops. sorry. it is VS2015 Express. I confused other Computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `#region` and `#endregion`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#region some stuff here
123;
456;
789;
#endregion some stuff here
int main() {
    print("hello world");
}
```